# Error Multiple Read 2D barcode from image ( A generic error occurred in GDI+.)

Tags: vb.net

I want to read 2D matrixcode from an image that I captured using camera and display it on a picturebox. The image will be saved from picturebox and then it will read the value of 2D matrixcode from the image.
I managed to read it one time. However, the second time I click the button to read it, it appeared this error. ": A generic error occurred in GDI+."

I want it able to capture it multiple time for each time I click.

Below are my attached code :

```
        Dim filepath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
        Dim current2 As Bitmap = CType(PictureBoxFilter.Image, Bitmap)
        Dim fileName2 As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(filepath, "test.png")
        current2.Save(fileName2)

        Dim decoder As DmtxImageDecoder = New DmtxImageDecoder()
        Dim codes As List(Of String) = decoder.DecodeImage(CType(Bitmap.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(filepath, "test.png")), Bitmap), 1, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 3))

        For Each code As String In codes

            If code <> "" Then

                Label1.Text = code
            Else
                Label1.Text = ""

            End If

        Next

        codes.Clear()

        current2.Dispose()
```

Comment: `DmtxImageDecoder` is not part of GDI.

Comment: @Dai I see. Do you have any suggestion how I can read it multiple time ?